# Google schema not working when sending emails through app

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to use Email Markup by Google to send event reservations and actions in my emails.

I have started by following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial) and it works fine.

Then, I have tried sending the same email through the app I have developed in C# in Visual Studio. The email gets sent fine but the markup is not there. I am sending the email from my email address to my email address using gmail's SMTP server so there are no issues related to the SPF etc.

Here is my code:

**reservation.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@context":              "http://schema.org",
        "@type":                 "EventReservation",
        "reservationNumber":     "IO12345",
        "underName": {
        "@type":               "Person",
        "name":                "John Smith"
        },
        "reservationStatus":     "booked",
        "reservationFor": {
        "@type":               "Event",
        "name":                "Google I/O 2013",
        "startDate":           "2017-09-09T08:30:00-08:00",
        "location": {
        "@type":             "Place",
        "name":              "Moscone Center",
        "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "800 Howard St.",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion":   "CA",
        "postalCode":      "94103",
        "addressCountry":  "US"
        }
        }
        }
        }
    </script>
    <p>
        Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
        BOOKING DETAILS<br />
        Reservation number: IO12345<br />
        Order for: John Smith<br />
        Event: Google I/O 2013<br />
        Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br />
        Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
private static void sendemail(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        string message=context.Request.Form["message"];
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject messageJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>(message);
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject messageResult = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();

        string email = messageJson["email"].ToString();
        string subject = messageJson["subject"].ToString();
        MailMessage emailmessage = new MailMessage();
        emailmessage.From = new MailAddress(email);
        emailmessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("myaddress@gmail.com"));
        emailmessage.Subject = subject;

        string email_body = File.ReadAllText("reservation.html");
        emailmessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        emailmessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        emailmessage.BodyTransferEncoding =System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
        emailmessage.Body = email_body;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host=myConfiguration.GetSection("SmtpServer").Value;
        client.Port = int.Parse(myConfiguration.GetSection("SmtpPort").Value);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myConfiguration.GetSection("Username").Value,myConfiguration.GetSection("Password").Value);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(emailmessage);

        messageResult["SmtpServer"] = myConfiguration.GetSection("SmtpServer").Value;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(messageResult.ToString());
    });
}
```

My impression is that it is not an issue in my code that is preventing the event from being added to the email, rather it is gmail blocking it.

I had a look at other posts but they were not of much help unfortunately.

Has anyone had the same problem and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your implementation is not working, it may seems that there is something missing along the process.

Follow these steps provided by [Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview), you maybe find some essential points there.

> - When you are ready to launch your marked up emails to your users, you will need to register with Google. Please follow this process:
> - Make sure that you meet all the guidelines and requirements listed below. Send a real-life email coming from your production servers (or
>     a server with similar DKIM/SPF/From:/Return-Path: headers) including
>     the markup / schema to schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com. We need
>     this in order to check that you comply with all the guidelines and
>     requirements listed in [Registration Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines).
>
>   - If you send a test/blank email, an email that does not contain schema or if you don't send an email for review your application will
>       be silently discarded.
>   - Make sure that the markup is correct prior to sending the email. For more details see [Testing your Schema](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema). Especially make sure the
>       email passes the [Email markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) and that there are no errors,
>       also make sure to include as much data as possible.
>   - Gmail removes all markup when forwarding an email. Do not forward the email but send it directly.
> - Fill out the [registration form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfT5F1VJXtBjGw2mLxY2aX557ctPTsCrJpURiKJjYeVrugHBQ/viewform?pli=1) and we will get back to you.

Comment: I am still at the developement stage so I would prefer to stick to sending emails from my address to my address which should work fine considering that when I use the tutorial script in script.google.com it works perfectly.